# Ruby 2.0.0-p353, Rails 4.0.2, Netbeans 7.4 - Cannot start webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

I am trying to use netbeans 7.4 with Ruby 2.0.0-p353 and Rails 4.0.2. Plugin seems to work ok. I am able to generate project and everything is there, but when I try to run project I receive following message and server is not started:

`C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)`

There is a comment under official plugin page that says:

> I found a simple workaround, I'm using Windows 7 and created a
>   symbolic link between directories like this:  mklink /D script bin 
>   Now I can start and debug my Rails 4 project in Netbeans.  Posted by
>   mgard on Aug 19, 2013

I have tried to do this but it still doesn't solve a problem. Is there anybody that can help?

Comment: Your workaround worked to me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution works well from what I have seen.  What is the error you are getting?  Are you able to create directory link?  You would need Admin rights for that and should start the command prompt "Run as Administrator".  Alternatively, try right-clicking on the "bin" directory and execute "Create shortcut" that must be renamed to "script" later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Aptana on Win 8 and came to the problem.

Now rails 4 doesn't have script/rails in the folder. We will need to create it manually in your application folder. You can simply create the folder, then mklink or copy the file in the script folder. Please take caution that your IDE will have proper access to the file you create, otherwise, you will come to the error:

c:\Ruby200\bin\rubyw.EXE: No such file or directory -- C:/Users/Zhou/Documents/GitHub/HR-SNA/script/rails (LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

Go to project's root directory and execute from a console following command:

```
ln -s ./bin ./script
```

In Rails 4, script has been replaced with bin